# setState update value based on stream

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I am trying to set value inside stream builder, but when I want to set a value using setState function, i get this error.

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

Here is my snipped

```
int countRecent = 0;

...

return StreamBuilder<Object>(
      stream: Data(uid: user.uid).getTrips,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        dynamic items = snapshot.data;
        setState(() => countRecent = items.length);
} 

...

Text(
  "$countRecent",
  style: TextStyle(
   color: Colors.white,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
     fontSize: 43,
     letterSpacing: 0.2,
     fontFamily: "VarelaRound",
  ),
),
```

Basically, what I want is to update this variable each time, document change (or rather length of this document.)

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: If an answer fixed your issue, remember to mark it as correct so that it can help other users in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just display your `Text` with the data you get on your `StreamBuilder`:

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: Data(uid: user.uid).getTrips,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    dynamic items = snapshot.data;
    return Text(
      "${items.length}",
      style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
        fontSize: 43,
        letterSpacing: 0.2,
        fontFamily: "VarelaRound",
      ),
    )
  } 
);
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Streams and widgets that use them can be confusing at first, but once you get the hang of them you will be using them easily. Good luck with your app!

Comment: what if we want to stop the stream because no longer needed but still want to have the last update/value of a variable that was from stream?

Comment: You could simply save them to variables on your class, doing the assignment inside the builder, before the return.

Comment: I have a similar situation, but i want the data (result of streambuilder) to be displayed in a Drawer in the AppBar so i cannot move the code into the streambuilder as suggested here. How do i do it ?

Comment: @vikasm You should post a new question if this one doesn't fit what you are looking for. Remember to share your code and a clear explanation of what you are trying to achieve.